# Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I tried to create admin user using php artisan tinker. When I try to save, it return an error. Please help me to fix the issue.

Here is the error

> Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]:
>   Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'admin' in 'field list' (SQL:
>   update `users` set `updated_at` = 2018-12-28 05:41:31, `admin` = 1
>   where `id` = 1)'

[image]

Comment: You don`t have ```admin``` column in you ```User``` table.

Comment: @Saji show ur `User` model in question

Answer (score 1):

You have no column named 'admin' in 'users' table of your database. Add an 'admin' column.
This should solve the error.

Comment: Done. But then return another error "PHP Error:  Call to undefined method stdClass::save() in Psy Shell code on line 1"

Comment: Try this

$me = new App\User

$me = App\User::find(1)

$me->admin = 1

$me->save()

Answer (score 0):

Please remove `admin` in `$fillable` and try again

Answer (score 0):

You must create a migration containing the new columns you want to add to your DB schema.

Example: (this will add a TINYINT `admin` column with `0` as default value)

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class AddsAdminColumnToUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->tinyInteger('admin')->default(0);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('admin');
        });
    }
}
```

[Read more about Laravel Migrations here.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations)